# XML file with 11 character timestamps

Tags: xml, timestamp

I have been given an XML file from a client relationship database with 7 million rows. All timestamps are in this format:

```
<Timestamp>AAAAAAAKkVY=</Timestamp>
AAAAAAARx2M
AAAAAAAVT30
```

It appears the first 7 characters are always "A's"
Could the last 4 digits be a HEX code or something similar?
Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated `A` at the beginning are [Base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) zeros. The length of the first string `AAAAAAAKkVY=` is 12, indicating that the original value is 8 bytes.

Assuming these values are representing 8-byte integers, you can do this in Python:

```
import struct

x = 'AAAAAAAKkVY='.decode('base64')  # Base64-decode the string
n = struct.unpack('>q', x)[0]        # Convert the bytes to an 8-byte int
print(n)
```

Output: `692566`

The other two strings seem to be missing `=` padding. Adding the padding and decoding them gives:

- `AAAAAAARx2M=`: `1165155`
- `AAAAAAAVT30=`: `1396605`

Without more context, it is not really possible to know how those are timestamps. Also keep in mind that the numbers could be 8-byte floating-point value (doubles), but that's unlikely given the zeros at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for that, the only context in the XML file is: <Timestamp>AAAAAAAKkVY=</Timestamp>.          692566 in Excel gives 5/3/3796. How do I convert to correct date?

Comment: These value seem to be relative to a starting point (time 0). Could be milli- or micro-seconds? It really depends on the scale

Comment: That's what I mean by context. Are these small-scale timings (milliseconds)? or are they larger-scale (days, months, etc.)?